# Incrementing value in Access query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to increment a value in a query. This is an id field that was set up as a Number field. I need to insert multiple records into a table.

The field cannot be an AutoNumber field, as the ID is used elsewhere and some values are not incremented by 1.

How do I get the ID field to increment when appending?

I tried:

```
DMax('[fieldName]', '[tableName]') + 1
```

This gets the first record but then fails to add the rest of the query.

If I put it in a while loop then it only ever adds the first entry but does increment the id field.

Comment: All solutions will be prone to error on a multi-user environment. Copy the existing table and paste in-place (select the structure only option), change the field to auto-number and then run an import query from the old table. Once done, delete the old and rename. Work on a copy of the database to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The field unfortunately cannot be an AutoNumber field, as the ID is used elsewhere and some values are not incremented by 1, but for the purpose of the button I want to add it does need to increment by 1. I am also currently working in a copy of the database as I am messing around with the raw data, but that is a great tip.

Comment: I've had this problem.  If the answer is not working for you then you are still better off adapting Kostas's solution.    Do all the following in a rediculously safe manner.  Add an autonumber field to the table.  temporarily delete all table relationships involving the original pk.  at this point all instances of originalpk in other tables are just numbers and I will call them originalfk.  at this point each value of originalpk has a newpk so use update queries to replace each orginalfk with the corresponding newfk.  then restore all the table relationships and you are done.

Comment: forgot to mention before restoring the relationships.  delete originalpk, then rename newpk to originalpk then restore all the relationships

Answer (score 0):

As is, it will only be calculated once when you run the query.

You can force an update by including a dummy criteria where you concatenate a table field:

```
DMax('[fieldName]', '[tableName]', '' & [SomeField] & ' Is Not Null') + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. When I add the criteria I'm getting an enter parameter box, so it's not picking up the field value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry ignore that last one, it was because the table isn't part of the query. If I add the table to the query then it won't append any records because the tables have a relationship.